# How to integrate ATOM Push in iPhone SDK

Tags: iphone, push-notification

Any one know how to register ATOM push from Iphone Device. I am really stuck at this point.

Just Check Last Screenshot of this application

http://itunes.apple.com/in/app/weather-alert-usa/id314502416?mt=8

Also have list of city and state from http://alerts.weather.gov/. I need to register alerts for this county.

If any one know it please respond me.

Thanks 
Ashish

Answer (score 0):

For push notifications you will need to setup a push server. You can't use an other apps push server because the app identifier will not match.

Here is a nice tutorial on push servers: http://blog.boxedice.com/2009/07/10/how-to-build-an-apple-push-notification-provider-server-tutorial/